# React changing song in playlist, useEffect hook dependency array

Tags: reactjs, ajax, use-effect

#### Problem Description

I am making a playlist player using [Soundcloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing) and encounter a problem when clicking on next/previous buttons to change to the next song. The initial song is fetched successfully using `useEffect` hook, but I don't know how to call this hook again when `onClick()` method is executed within next/previous buttons.

Currently, the play/pause button works correctly, but the next/previous buttons only work under some specific sequence of clicks involving { play/pause/previous/next } buttons. That is expected given that my useEffect hooks seem erroneous.

#### JSFiddle (Wasn't able to insert Stackoverflow JS/HTML/CSS widjet)

[[-------- Working JSFiddle here !!---------]](https://jsfiddle.net/rj6qL8ug/)

#### Playlist.tsx

```
import react, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const SC = require('soundcloud');

SC.initialize({
  client_id: '1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9'
});

const playlist = [
    913128502,
    755552476,
    604329399
]

const playIcon = 'https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/20-201074_play-button-png-image-background- 
circle-transparent-png.png';
const pauseIcon = 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/pause-button-icon-transparent-background- 
sign-flat-style-204042531.jpg';
const prevIcon = 'https://i.postimg.cc/xCry8pgt/prev2.png';
const nextIcon = 'https://i.postimg.cc/ncwmMwhB/next.png';

const musicFetch = (trackId) => {
   return SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackId)
     .then(track => {
        return track;
   })
}    

const Playlist = () => {
   const [playState, setPlayState] = useState(false);
   const [track, setTrack] = useState<any>(null);
   const [playlistIndex, setPlaylistIndex] = useState(0);
  


    // use effect that fetches the initial song upong first render
    useEffect(() => {
        musicFetch(playlist[playlistIndex]).then((music) => {
          music.setVolume(0.025); //increase if you don't hear background sound
          setTrack(music);
        });
    }, [])
 
    // use effect that should fetch new song upon clicking next or previous button
    useEffect(() => {
        musicFetch(playlist[playlistIndex]).then((music) => {
          music.setVolume(0.2); //increase if you don't hear background sound
          setTrack(music);
        });
    }, [setPlayState, playlistIndex])
  
    const handleClick = async (direction) => {
        direction === 'play' ? await enableMusic() : await changeMusic(direction);
    }
 
    const enableMusic = async () => {
        if (track) {
            setPlayState(!playState);
            playState ? await track.pause() : await track.play();
        }
    }
 
    const changeMusic = async (direction) => {
        setPlaylistIndex(
            direction === 'next' ? await playlistIndex+1 : await playlistIndex-1
        );
    }
    return (
        <div>
           <img src={prevIcon} 
                onClick={() => { handleClick('prev') }}
                height="100" width="100"/>
           <img src={!playState ? playIcon : pauseIcon } 
                onClick={() => { handleClick('play') }}
                height="100" width="100" >
           </img>
           <img src={nextIcon}
                onClick={() => { handleClick('next') }}
                height="100" width="100"/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Playlist;
```

---

#### Things I have tried

I have read about `useEffect` hook conditional dependency array, and tried to set in my useEffect hook any combination involving `setPlaylistindex`,`playlistIndex`, `setTrack`, but with no success. I have considered the `useCallback` hook but that doesn't seem to be the correct solution.

I tried to find a way to dismount and mount, such that the empty dependency useEffect hook is called upon request, I was able to design a `forceUpdate()` for that matter, but that didn't fix the problem either.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wire the dependencies in your `useEffect` hook correctly.

Have separate `useEffect` hooks to capture play/pause and play list index state changes. You can add dependency for `track` to the `useEffect` hook that handles play/pause state changes and remove any other `useEffect` hooks, including the one with empty dependency list.

```
React.useEffect(async () => {
    const music = await musicFetch(playlist[playlistIndex]);
    music.setVolume(0.2);
    setTrack(music);
 }, [playlistIndex]);
 
 React.useEffect(async ()=>{
    playState ? await track.play() : await track.pause();
 }, [track, playState]);
```

You can then refactor `enableMusic` method as follows

```
 const enableMusic = async () => {
        if (track) {
        setPlayState(!playState);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use playState inside the depenendy array not the setPlayState you want to re-render on playState value change.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. But that does not fix the problem; next/previous buttons do not work. Can you provide a modified JSFiddle?